# Project not compiling after Dagger version update (FileTooBigException)

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, dagger

I have upgraded my project **Dagger version from 2.29.1 to 2.44**, but after the upgrade I am not able to compile the code.

This is the error I am getting:

```
e: org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.KotlinFrontEndException: Front-end Internal error: Failed to analyze declaration SomeExtnContractImpl
File being compiled: (97,1) in FILE_NAME.kt
The root cause org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileTooBigException was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtil.loadFileBytes(FileUtil.java:201)

Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileTooBigException: Attempt to load 'PROJECT_PATH/DaggeAppComponent.java' in memory buffer, file length is 24808949 bytes.
```

I have tired setting custom editor properties with these values (in KB):

```ini
idea.max.content.load.filesize=30000  
idea.max.intellisense.filesize=35000  
idea.max.vcs.loaded.size.kb=30000
```

But I'm still getting the same error. Please suggest what can be done to fix this?

Comment: Please file an issue to Dagger issue tracker with a sample project to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error, a possible workaround is to use this in `gradle.properties`

```
kotlin.daemon.jvmargs=-Didea.max.content.load.filesize=300000 -Didea.max.intellisense.filesize=300000
```

Note: *300000 here will be equivalent to 30 MB.*